Поясните логику алгоритма пожалуйста
Вот условие задачи:
На свой день рождения Мила получила строку S, состоящую из символов ‘0’ и ‘1’. Но Мила не считает эту строку красивой, поэтому решила ее исправить!
Мила определяет красивой строки следующим образом:

Разобьем строку на максимально длинные подстроки, состоящие из одинаковых символов.
Если все эти подстроки получились одинаковой длины, исходная строка считается красивой, а иначе — некрасивой.

Например, строка ‘010101’ разбивается на подстроки ‘0’, ‘1’, ‘0’, ‘1’, ‘0’, ‘1’ и поэтому является красивой, а строка ‘000101’ разбивается на подстроки ‘000’, ‘1’, ‘0’, ‘1’ и поэтому является некрасивой. Другие примеры красивых строк: ‘1’, ‘110011’, ‘00001111’, ‘00000000’. Другие примеры некрасивых строк: ‘011’, ‘010011’, ‘00110100’.
Мила просит вас посчитать, сколько минимум символов нужно изменить в строке S, чтобы сделать ее красивой.
Вот код решения задачи:

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       String line = sc.next();
       int ans = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
       for (int i = 1; i <= line.length(); i++) {
           if (line.length() % i == 0) {
               int minChanges = minChanges(i, line);
               ans = Math.min(ans, minChanges);
           }
       }
        System.out.println(ans);
    }

    private static int minChanges(int rangeLength, String line) {
        int rangeCount = line.length() / rangeLength;
        int startWithOnes = 0;
        int startWithZeroes = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rangeCount; i++) {
            int zeros = 0;
            int ones = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < rangeLength; j++) {
                char c = line.charAt(j + i * rangeLength);

                if (c == '0') {
                    zeros++;
                }

                if (c == '1') {
                    ones++;
                }

                startWithZeroes += (i % 2 == 0 ? zeros : ones);
                startWithOnes += (i % 2 == 0 ? ones : zeros);
            }
        }
        return Math.min(startWithOnes, startWithZeroes);
    }
}

Я не могу понять, что вообще считает переменная startWithZeroes и startWithOnes. Я полагал, что она считает сколько надо сделать действий для строки, чтобы каждый подраздел(переменная i) начинался с 0 или 1. Если у нас i делит строку на сегменты по 1 элементу, тогда совпадает с ручными расчетами(на примерах можно убедится).
000101 - изначальная строка, как я понимаю что надо чтобы каждый четный сегмент начинался с 0, а так как сегмент изначально рассматривается по одному числу в сегменте получим 010101(затратили 1 замену). Если начинался с 1 то получим 101010(затратили 5 замен). Тут все совпало.
Дальше берем сегмент по 2(i = 2). если чтобы четные сегменты были нули. Получим 001100 при этом затратив 3 действия. Если чтобы четные сегменты единицы то 110011 затратив 4, а по просмотру дебаг будет startWithOnes = 3, startWithZeroes = 6. Подскажите пожалуйста как тогда надо действовать чтоб совпадать с алгоритмом.

Даже если взять предположение, что мы превратим 000101 в 010101(затратили 1 действие), 101010(затратили 5) то тоже не совпадает

Вы нашли чужой код и просите его объяснить?

В этом коде есть ошибка. Вы могли бы три раза уже решить задачу, вместо этого теряете время на отладку чужого кода. Или это я его теряю?

Найдите чужой код, но правильный.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, если вы видите ошибку можете сказать где. Я прошу объяснить что именно считают две переменные, ибо данный код по тестам проходит и является решением задачи

Этот код для строки 100111 выдаёт ответ 2. Правильный ответ - 1, достаточно изменить первую единицу на ноль, чтобы сделать её красивой  - 000111. Таким образом этот код содержит ошибку и не может проходить тесты. Бесполезно рассуждать что считают эти две переменные.

@Kiawem Собственно, идея алгоритма рабочая, попробуйте сами аккуратно реализовать.


$ javac Main.java

$ echo 000111 | java Main
0

$ echo 100111 | java Main
2


В этих двух примерах строки различаются на один символ, а ответы на две единицы. Второй ответ ошибочен.
Следовательно, программа содержит ошибку, пояснять логику алгоритма бесполезно.
Если вынести операторы += из внутреннего цикла, ошибка пропадает:

------
< 
<                 startWithZeroes += (i % 2 == 0 ? zeros : ones);
<                 startWithOnes += (i % 2 == 0 ? ones : zeros);
<             }
======
> 
>             }
>             startWithZeroes += (i % 2 == 0 ? zeros : ones);
>             startWithOnes += (i % 2 == 0 ? ones : zeros);
------


С этим изменением алгоритм становится рабочим. Но всё ещё не эффективен. Можно привести примеры (длин) строк на которых программа будет работать за квадратичное время. Хорошая задача состоит в том чтобы решить её быстрее чем за квадрат.
P.S. Не совсем ответ на ваш вопрос, извините. Скорее объяснение недостатков самого вопроса.
P.P.S. Программы у которых минимум на внешнем цикле, хорошо скрывают ошибки во внутренних циклах. Даже если там наврано, программа продолжает выдавать правдоподобные результаты в большинстве случаев. Часто поймать такую ошибку можно только написав правильную программу и сравнив результаты.
P.P.P.S. Не тратьте время на чужой код, сперва изучите саму задачу.
